# VBA Range.FindNext just finds next cell, not next search term

Tags: excel, vba

I am still quite new to VBA and decided I would try and teach myself the `Range.FindNext` method. Unfortunately, I am not very successful so far.

What I am trying to do, is to copy all rows with a specific search term in them to a new sheet (could be anything, therefore declared as a `Variant`). What is important, is that the search term might only be part of the cell's value, hence I am using `xlPart` in my `Range.Find` method.

Here the example data from my `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet`:

```
Date        Name        Numbers
12.04.2012  Marla       45653
13.04.2017  Peter       23545
27.04.1985  Bertrud     46932
16.08.2020  Peterson    46764
15.09.2014  Marcos      32465
21.06.2010  Peter Pan   23452
31.08.2013  Bernard     12321
```

So, when looking for "Peter", I should be getting rows 3, 5 and 7 in a new sheet. This is the code I wrote for this:

```
Option Explicit
Dim wsMain, wsNew As Worksheet
Dim rgAll, rgSearchTermFind As Range
Dim varSearchTerm As Variant
Dim lngLastRow, lngLastColumn As Long
Dim firstAddress As String

Public Sub FindAndCopy()

'I have an InputBox for the user to determine the varSearchTerm, but for this example:
varSearchTerm = "Peter"

Set wsMain = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet    
Set wsNew = Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count))

Call FindLast(wsMain) 'This is a separate sub I wrote to find the last row & column
With wsMain
    Set rgAll = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lngLastRow, lngLastColumn))
End With

With rgAll
    Set rgSearchTermFind = .Find(What:=varSearchTerm, _
                                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                    SearchOrder:=xlNext, _
                                    MatchCase:=False)

    If Not rgSearchTermFind Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = rgSearchTermFind.Address

        Do
            'Copy row to new sheet
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(wsNew.Cells) <> 0 Then
                Call FindLast(wsNew) 'This is a separate sub I wrote to find the last row & column
                wsMain.Range(rgSearchTermFind.Address).EntireRow.Copy _
                Destination:=wsNew.Cells(lngLastRow + 1, 1)
            Else
                wsMain.Range(rgSearchTermFind.Address).EntireRow.Copy _
                Destination:=wsNew.Cells(1, 1)
            End If

            'Find next occurrence of search term
            Set rgSearchTermFind = .FindNext(rgSearchTermFind)
        Loop Until rgSearchTermFind.Address = firstAddress
    Else
        'Code here to execute if search term could not be found
    End If 
End With
End Sub
```

When running this code, the initial `Range.Find` method finds Peter in B3, but the `Range.FindNext` then finds "Bertrud" in B4 and copies it. This happens for each cell in the range, leaving me at the end with the table copied three times in the new sheet (due to there being three columns).

What am I doing wrong? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you used any Range.Find method in those others subroutine? Cause i might have missed something, but the code seems to work to me and it fails if i make it call another sub where i use a Range.Find method.

Comment: That seems improbable. Have you stepped through to see what's going on? Btw `wsMain.Range(rgSearchTermFind.Address)` is just `rgSearchTermFind`.

Comment: Your code seems to work here, also, returning the three rows you state.

Comment: Going by the name and description of `FindLast` I'm guessing it includes `.Find("*", ...)`  If it does, then `FindNext` repeats _that_ search, not the original one.  You'll need a different method to track LastCell in wsNew.  That said, once you've fixed it, I'd suggest taking your working code to Code Review,  there are a lot of other opportunities to improve here.

Comment: @chrisneilsen Thanks! I did use `.Find("*", ...)` in the `Find Last` subroutine. Once I fixed that, the code work perfectly!

Comment: @SJR Thanks for pointing that out! I've changed it in my code now.